# What is the phrase for "getting to know" someone or something?

Tags: phrases

My question is how is the concept of "getting to know" or "knowing" someone conveyed? How do you invite someone to get to know you better? 
I was posting a message on mixi and could not figure out what the phrase for this was.

Sentence example so you can understand contextually...

If I sound nice, then don't be scared to get to know me.
or
I'd prefer not to talk about that until I know you better.

How do I express this in japanese? Are there stock phrases? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

知{し}り合{あ}う is used for "getting to know"; with the noun 知り合い being used to mean "an acquaintance" or "someone you know a little (less that a close friend)".

---

**Examples**

> - 留学の時、ほかの留学生と**知り合った**のに、親しい関係だとは言えない。　→　During my time as an exchange student, even though I got to know some of the other exchange students, I wouldn't (can't) really say I was close with any of them.
> - 最近通っているラーメン屋さんと**知り合い**になっている。　→　I've been getting to know the owner(s) of the ramen shop (that) I've been going to lately.
> - あの子はほんの**知り合い**にすぎません。　→　That girl is nothing more than an acquaintance. (Not sure if the ほんの here is derogatory or not ー
>     I feel like it might be).

Comment: A little more useful than plain "知り合い": 知り合いになる (e.g.: 知り合いになった = "got acquainted") is quite common...

Comment: I'm wondering if we could brainstorm some example sentences to improve this answer.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. I will be giving this phrase a spin in the near future.  
But it really would be awesome to see example sentences instead of me posting my sentences in google to see if natives phrase it the same, lol.

Answer (score 0):

for peeps:
知り合う　or as it was covered above:
近く・ as in literally get close to someone. XXさんと近くなりたい. Depending on the context it isn't always sexual.

In a letter from my Mother in law I once saw 懇意になる but that's my only encounter with it.

For inanimate stuff you'd probably be best using なれる which i often use in the following sentence.

英語のキーは人気だけど、使ったことなければなれるのはちょっと時間がかかる可能性があります。